# OpenID SSO in Websphere Liberty requires authentication every time I reopen a browser

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, openid, websphere-liberty

I've defined Websphere Liberty to use [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect) Provider by using following feature: [openidConnectClient-1.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_openidConnectClient-1.0.html).

Everything works file except that Liberty requires from user to authenticate every time it open browser, i.e. closing browser removing all authentication details. What's wrong with my configuration or maybe I've missed something?

`server.xml`:

---

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>openidConnectClient-1.0</feature>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    <feature>webCacheMonitor-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
</featureManager>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="xxxxxxx"/>

<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<openidConnectClient authFilterRef="applicationFilter"
                     authorizationEndpointUrl="https://xxxxxxxxxxx/authorize" 
                     clientId="xxxxxxxx"
                     clientSecret="xxxxxxxxxx" 
                     createSession="false" 
                     disableLtpaCookie="false" 
                     grantType="authorization_code" 
                     httpsRequired="true" 
                     id="sso_liberty" 
                     issuerIdentifier="https://xxxxxxxx" 
                     responseType="code" 
                     scope="openid" 
                     signatureAlgorithm="RS256" 
                     tokenEndpointAuthMethod="post" 
                     tokenEndpointUrl="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/token" 
                     trustAliasName="application_sso" 
                     trustStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" 
                     userIdentityToCreateSubject="sub">
</openidConnectClient>

<ltpa expiration="100h" 
        keysFileName="${server.output.dir}/resources/security/ltpa_new.keys" 
        keysPassword="xxxxx"/>
<authCache timeout="100h"/>

<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>


<ldapRegistry baseDN="O=xxxxxx.COM" 
                host="xxxxx.xxxxx.com" 
                id="LDAP" 
                ignoreCase="true" 
                ldapType="IBM Tivoli Directory Server" 
                port="xxxxx" 
                realm="xxxxxxxxx" 
                searchTimeout="8m">
    <idsFilters groupFilter="xxxxxx" 
                    groupIdMap="xxxx"  
                    groupMemberIdMap="xxxxx" 
                    userFilter="xxxxx" 
                    userIdMap="xxxxx">
    </idsFilters>
</ldapRegistry>

<authFilter id="applicationFilter">
    <webApp id="application.angular" matchType="contains" name="application.angular"/>
    <requestUrl matchType="notContain" urlPattern="/api/icalfeed"/>
</authFilter>

<webApplication id="application.angular" location="application.angular.war" name="application.angular">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, third-party"  />
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="All Role">
            <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</webApplication>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User's authentication status is maintained by your SSO server. If Liberty security session expires or browser is closed and reopened, Liberty will redirect user to SSO server, and user will not be prompted for relogin if browser still maintains a valid session with SSO server. However, if your SSO server uses browser session cookie to maintain user's authentication status, user will be asked to relogin to your SSO server. So the behavior is controlled by SSO server.

Comment: Can I use `ltpa` tokens to extend login time?

Comment: Liberty openid connect client can be configured to use ltpa expiration time as session time, or use id_token life time as session time. The default behavior is ltpa expiration time, and you can increase ltpa expiration time.

Comment: You can see that I tried to achieve it, my `ltpa` expiration time in my `server.xml` is `100h` but it doesn't work. Maybe I didn't describe myself in a right way but I meant how to use `ltpa` to expend login time.

Comment: ltpa cookie is a browser session cookie, if browser is closed, ltpa cookie is gone. What is your sso server? Can SSO server maintain authentication session after browser is reopened? If SSO server can not maintain authenticated user session, user will have to relogin