# 'Disabling' LTPA things in a Liberty server - am I missing something?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am investigating the notion of 'disabling' LTPA things in Liberty and would like some guidance. There are 2 ideas I am pursuing - first, is it possible to prevent a Liberty server from generating LTPA keys? and second, is it possible to prevent a Liberty server from sending an LTPA token/cookie to a client browser?

Before making this post, I went through the Liberty documentation. This topic in the Liberty KC https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ltpa.html states the following - "The LTPA is configured by default when security is enabled for a Liberty server for the first time." This is pretty clear that as long as I have security enabled for a Liberty server, it is going to generate LTPA keys; and disabling security in the Liberty server is not an option for me. So I do not believe that I can prevent the Liberty server from generating LTPA keys in my particular environment.

As for preventing a Liberty server from sending an LTPA token/cookie to a client browser, there appears to be an attribute called disableLtpaCookie that exists for a Liberty server. However, according to the Liberty documentation, I can use the disableLtpaCookie attribute in only 2 cases - when I am using the OpenID Connect Client https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.base.doc/ae/rwlp_config_openidConnectClient.html OR when I am using SAML Web SSO 2.0 Authentication https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.base.doc/ae/rwlp_config_samlWebSso20.html . If I am not implementing either of these authentication mechanisms, then I cannot use the disableLtpaCookie attribute...and thus I cannot prevent a Liberty server from sending an LTPA token/cookie to a client browser.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to prevent a Liberty server from generating LTPA keys or a way to prevent a Liberty server from sending an LTPA token/cookie to a client browser that I have not yet discovered through the Liberty documentation?

Any and all guidance is deeply appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LTPA cookie is required for Form login and Single-Sign-On to work out of box. If you are completely relying on other authentication mechanisms/tokens to achieve these (SAML, custom, OIDC etc), and have no reason to use the LTPA cookie, you can use set the singleSignonEnabled attribute to false in the webAppSecurity element.

<webAppSecurity singleSignonEnabled="false">

This should prevent the LTPACookie from being sent to the browser. The LTPA keys are still generated.

We can update the description of this property to make it more clear @ https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_webAppSecurity.html

You can open an issue to have an option to disable the creation of the LTPA keys.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance Ajay :-)  Unfortunately, our application does use FormLogin and thus setting the singleSignonEnabled="false" attribute in the webAppSecurity element does more harm than good as it basically prevents anyone from logging into our application :-)    Of course, I am curious if there a way to workaround the LTPA cookie requirement when our application does use FormLogin  :-)

Comment: You do need that for form-login to work out of box since the token in the cookie contains the user authenticated information that will be used after re-direction and later w/o having to prompt the user again. So what exactly is your scenario? Why do you not want the LTPA Cookie?

Comment: Long story short - Customers want to remain logged into our application indefinitely and we are investigating ways to achieve this.  We are aware of the expiration attribute in the ltpa element and are also investigating setting its value to meet customers' requirements.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment - Customers do not want the LTPA token to control the session validity time and we are investigating ways to achieve this.

Comment: @DavidWarnke If customer DONT want ltpa token to impact session timeout , just increase its validity to some high number, like 20 hours. Then you will be able to force any session validity via your application. Removing ltpa token is not a good idea.

Comment: One alternative solution is to create a standalone Liberty server as Openid Connect server. You can have Liberty OIDC server to handle form login, and have all other Liberty servers as Openid Connect relying party (so you can remove LTPA cookie from application server), and you only have one ltpa cookie (for the openid connect server)

Answer (score 0):

In this question/thread - [OpenID SSO in Websphere Liberty requires authentication every time I reopen a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747465/openid-sso-in-websphere-liberty-requires-authentication-every-time-i-reopen-a-br)     the following statement was made:

Liberty openid connect client can be configured to use ltpa expiration time as session time, or use id_token life time as session time.  The default behavior is ltpa expiration time.

I have not been able to find clear Liberty documentation explaining how to configure the Liberty openid connect client to use id_token life time as the session time....any guidance is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Once you set disableLtpaCookie="true", ltpa cookie is not created, and session cookie is created with id_token expiration time as session cookie's expiration time

Comment: If I remove 'singleSignonEnabled', I get no error but I do see 'ltpaToken2' cookie in browser.  If I set 'singleSignonEnabled' to false, I get error ** CWWKS9106E: SSO Configuration error. FormLogin is configured for web application myApp-ear but SSO is not enabled in the security settings.  SSO must be enabled to use FormLogin.**.